# BCB CodeGuard Pointer arithmetic underrun

Tags: c++

What's wrong with this code? Althought, it can run without error, but if I set CodeGuard in it, it will cause a `Pointer arithmetic underrun` error.

I don't know where error is.

My tools is `BCB5`

```
using namespace std;

map<int, vector<String> > m1;
vector<String> v1, v2;
v1.push_back("NO1");

m1[1] = v1;  //error, Pointer arithmetic underrun
v2 = m1[1];

m1.insert(pair<int, vector<String> >(1, v1));
v2 = m1[1];   //error, Pointer arithmetic underrun

vector<String>::iterator it;

for(it = v2.begin(); it != v2.end(); ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Rick

Comment: Your code looks fine, can add the exact error log?

Comment: Could the class `String` be broken? You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Good point, does it run fine if you replace `String` with `std::string`?

Comment: `error: 'm' was not declared in this scope` .. just a heads up in case there's a typo in your code or you're missing a variable name somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, it's m1, here is my  [screen capture](http://postimg.org/image/yh0usvk4r/)

Comment: The program ran fine when compiled with `g++-5.2.0 -fsanitize=address`. There were no error reports from AddressSanitizer. Of course, this is using GCC's standard library instead of whatever Borland is using.